# Quartz.NET seems to not work correctly with days of week

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

I am only using `CronExpression` at this time. Let's suppose I have the following expression: `0 35 09 ? * 2` This should mean (https://crontab.cronhub.io/):

[image]

And this is what I want.

Now let's try with some timestamp: `2024.02.06 09:35:00`. As far as I know, today is Tuesday. The time should match also.

```
var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2024.02.06 09:35:00");

dto.Dump(dto.DayOfWeek.ToString());
var co2 = new CronExpression("0 35 09 ? * 2");
co2.IsSatisfiedBy(dto).Dump();
```

The result:

[image]

But:

```
var co3 = new CronExpression("0 35 09 ? * 3");
co3.IsSatisfiedBy(dto).Dump("0 35 09 ? * 3");
```

Yields:

[image]

This means that it satisfies a pattern that has *Wednesday* in it.

On the other hand:

```
var next = co2.GetNextValidTimeAfter(dto);
next.Dump($"{next.Value.DayOfWeek}");
co2.IsSatisfiedBy(next.Value).Dump();
```

Yields:

[image]

And that is also confusing as, the pattern `0 35 09 ? * 1`, that has Monday in is not satisfied.

Am I doing something wrong here, or there is a bug in Quartz.Net?

**[Update]**

It is a bug. For anybody interested, Fix PR-ed: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/pull/2274

**[Update 2]**
"It's not a bug, it's a feature". For whatever reason the author(s) of Quartz.NET have chosen to go against the Cron "standard" of DOW 1-7 meaning MON-SUN, by implementing 1-7 to be SUN-SAT. Breaking any potential compatibility with standard tools. Hence my PR would break this break...

Comment: Nooe. I have tried with utc as well. Btw, the local time is +1, hence 9:35 is not in the range that can be affected by this.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment after testing this. Looks like a bug to me

Comment: "Let's make our library cron-compatible. But not too compatible, that would be too easy". Jokes aside, I reckon your proposed patch should be to create an overload ctor where you can specify `weekStartsOnMonday` or `zeroIndexedSunday` or something, so that it doesn't break usages of the existing API.